# How to call variable from function of a class into another function of same class

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

In a class circle I am two functions and I wish to use the variable self.area_y of equals method in compare method:

```
Class circle:
    @classmethod
    def compare(self, circle):
        self.x = circle
        self.area_x = math.pi*self.x*self.x
        #print area_x
        if self.area_x > self.area_y:
            return 1
        elif self.area_x < self.area_y:
            return -1
        elif self.area_x == self.area_y:
            return 0
        else:
            print "Undesired condition met!"

    @classmethod
    def equals(self, circle):
        self.y = circle
        self.area_y = math.pi*self.y*self.y
        return self.area_y

def main():
    circle_r1 = 14.50
    circle_r2 = 14.98
    circle.compare(circle_r1)
    circle.equals(circle_r2)
main()
```

However i get the following error when i try to do so:

```
File "C:/Users/Deepak/PycharmProjects/Submission/Shapes.py", line 97, in 
compare
if self.area_x > self.area_y:
AttributeError: class circle has no attribute 'area_y'
```

What should i do to get rid of the issue.Its worthwhile to note that i am calling both of these functions from main class later.Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an init function (also called a constructor).

Inside of the init function you would add the variables that need to be shared between functions (so in this case that would be self.area and self.radius).

In the code below you'll notice that in the main function I'm creating multiple objects of the Circle class. That's the way objects usually work. Each time you create an object, the object gets its own compare and equals functions that you can use. The object can also have its own data assigned to it. The class just defines the instructions for how its object should be created. You can google the distinction between the two for more info.

So, in your case, instead of saying `Circle.compare(14.50)`, You would create a new object `circle1 = Circle(14.50)`, and you would give that object a radius. That radius will be saved as belonging to circle1 (because we told the init function to save it). Then, instead of doing `circle.compare(14.50)` you can use functions that belong to circle1 `circle1.compare(circle2)`.

```
import math

class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
        self.area = math.pi*radius*radius

    def compare(self, other):
        if self.area > other.area:
            return 1
        elif self.area < other.area:
                return -1
        elif self.area == other.area:
                return 0
        else:
            print("Undesired condition met!")

    def equals(self, other):
        return self.area == other.area

def main():
    circle_r1 = Circle(14.50) 
    circle_r2 = Circle(14.98)
    print( circle_r1.compare(circle_r2) )
    print( circle_r1.equals(circle_r2) )
main()
```

A few more items that you may or may not already know:

The current object is held inside of the self variable, so when we say self.radius, we're talking about the radius variable for the current object.

To tell objects and classes apart, class names are usually capitalized, while objects are not.

As soon as we create a circle object `circle1 = Circle(14.50)`, the init function is called, and our object gets prepped with its own radius and area variables.

I saw that you where using the classmethod decorator. You generally don't need to use class methods. If you want to better understand class methods, I would suggest researching staticmethod first, and then once you understand static methods, then look up classmethod.